# Import "flask" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python, flask

Appreciate that this has been asked before, but I have tried the suggestions to no avail.

[a snip of flask not loading, with pip show flask output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzld2.png)

VSCode is telling me that: *Import "flask" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource)*

Running `export` shows me:

```sh
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
```

I can run `flask run` and my app works, but when I run `pytest`, I receive:

```
______________________ ERROR collecting tests/unit/test_app.py ______________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/myname/projects/flask-stock-portfolio/tests/unit/test_app.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/unit/test_app.py:4: in <module>
    from app import app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Where **test_app.py** reads:

```py
"""
This file (test_app.py) contains the unit tests for the app.py file.
"""
from app import app

def test_index_page():
    """
    GIVEN a Flask application
    WHEN the '/' page is requested (GET)
    THEN check the response is valid
    """
    with app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.get('/')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert b'Flask Stock Portfolio App' in response.data
        assert b'Welcome to the Flask Stock Portfolio App!' in response.data
```

Anything you can do to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are asking about 2 issues: 1- the pylance one is about VS Code settings/configuration, 2- the pytest one is about running pytest in the correct virtual environment. The title is only about the 1st one. Both look related to virtual environment, but these are really 2 separate issues (ex. you can make pylance work but pytest still fails). There's probably a duplicate somewhere. Can you please re-focus your question to pick one problem at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your current working directory to the python search path. This can be done with an environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

Alternatively you can do it from within Python. I usually put this in my `conftest.py` file in my tests folder, which is executed when pytest starts up.

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).parent.parent  # i.e. the folder above the tests folder, which has app
sys.path.append(path)
```

The VS Code error is a separate issue. It sounds like you might not have the correct Python environment selected. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Wonderful thank you! That's helped me fix both!

Comment: Selecting correct environment on VSCode fixed it.