# Import [Module] could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, pip, pymysql

I'm trying to import pymysql to my python script in VSCode but am getting the following error

```
Import "pymysql" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
```

I installed the module with pip the same way I have with all other modules such as Pandas, which works fine

Here's the import line for reference

```
import pymysql
```

Any quick fixes or explanations of what is going on would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for the current Python Interpreter VSCode is using `Ctrl+P`.
2. Add your virtual environment PATH where your module is installed in `'C:\Users\<username>\.virtualenvs\<virtualenvname>\Scripts\python'`.

Answer (score 1):

run python3 -m pip install pymysql
if you continue experiening the same proplem, please change your python interpreter from global to windows store from the interpreter section

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your current working directory to the Python search path. This can be done with an environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
```

There is a similar question here: [Import "flask" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67943847/import-flask-could-not-be-resolved-from-sourcepylancereportmissingmodulesource)

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip show pymysql` to check if module is installed in `\current selected interpreter\lib\site-packages`:

[image]

If not, please reinstall it to current used environment. If it is, open **Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P)** and choose **Reload Window**, the warning should go away.